# Filtering subforms using multiple ID values, no record source changes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've coded my entire database to rely on recordsets and updating those recordsets on click of record IDs within other forms. Then I discovered that I can't edit the records from the datasheet. So I need an alternative.

My database consists of the following tables: `Customer`, `Address`, `Order`, `Details`, `Contact` and `Misc`. Each of these tables has a PK which is stored in a table called `Master_Bridge` which constructs a unique combination of all the PKs.

I have a form which includes each of these tables as a subform. The user begins at the `Customer` subform. When they click the `Customer_ID`, the `Address` table needs to filter based on where that `Customer_ID` exists within the `Master_Bridge`.

I was hoping to store each of the IDs into a recordset, or an array of some type, and translate each of those values into the filter. Admittedly, my VBA isn't good enough that I know how to do that.

I also tried a nested select in the recordsource of the `Customer` form, where I selected all of the `Address_ID`s. Again, couldn't edit.

Do you folks have any suggestions on how to proceed with this? I'll also need the click of `Address_ID` to filter the `Order` form by using both the `Customer_ID` and the `Address_ID`. The rest of the tables/forms will utilize the above 3 IDs.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  1) First you say "Then I discovered that I **can** edit them"  and later you say "Again, **couldn't** edit".  So which is it?  Can you edit or not?  What is it that you can or cannot edit?  2)  The meaning of "translate each of those values into the filter" also is not clear.  What do you mean by "translate"?  3) The purpose and structure of the [Master_Bridge] table is not clear.  Pleased edit the question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Edited. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? Use regular one-to-many relations e.g. between Customer and Order. And use bound forms/subforms, so when the user selects a Customer, you filter the Order form for this Customer's orders.

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do - sounds like you're trying to get your subforms to stay in sync with your main form? If you click on the border of your subform the Property Sheet will allow you to link the Master/Child fields between the main/subform and that'll keep the records in sync.

Comment: For a form to be editable, the form's _Record Source_ query needs to be editable.  For a query to remain editable, the joins need to be on indexed primary / foreign keys fields with proper relationships.  Nested queries and mixed joins between multiple tables will surely lead to non-editable queries. I won't dismiss the `Master_Bridge` table immediately, but it does not conform to usual, normalized table design which is what Access forms are designed to handle.

Comment: You'll have better luck with proper foreign keys in each table, rather than one "master" link table. A third table can be necessary for many-to-many relationships, but handle that on a relationship by relationship case.  I honestly don't see a need for that in this type of database.  Example:  Address.CustomerID -> Customer.ID (many to one), likewise Contact.CustomerID -> Customer.ID, Order.CustomerID -> Customer.ID.  Details.OrderID -> Order.ID.  Some complexity can arise, like Order.ShippingAddressID -> Address.ID where you need some way to ensure that AddressID and CustomerID agree.